# How to store a field that only take reference to String created in `::new()`?

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

In the below code, how should I store a `B` field in `A`? Supposed that I can not change the [definition of `B`](https://docs.rs/suff_collections/latest/suff_collections/array/struct.SuffixArray.html#method.new).

As a newbie to Rust, I searched Google and most of them explain why the error happens. I could understand the compile error, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Or is it bad design to store the field in this case? Are there other solutions to this?

Thanks!

```
use std::io::Read;

struct A<'a> {
    b: B<'a>,
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    pub fn new(mut reader: impl Read) -> Self {
        let mut s = String::new();
        reader.read_to_string(&mut s);

        let b = B { b: &s };
        A { b }
    }
}

// From 3rd party library, can't change the struct!
struct B<'a> {
    b: &'a str,
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: you can't (in general there is some way but you don't want it). from few minutes study this crate look it's not a lot used, since it's lacking of a way to do what you want. I suggest you create an idea asking for a to_owned function that will make the CoW inside owned.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks for the suggestions. Can you also point me to the keywords of that "some way"? :)

Comment: there is reason of why I didn't

Comment: The answer is "don't do that". What yes? It depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in this case you need something to own the data. So just make your `A` to own it, and then have a method that creates the `B` type from `A`:

```rust
struct A {
    s: String,
}

// From 3rd party library, can't change the struct!
struct B<'a> {
    b: &'a str,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new(mut reader: impl Read) -> Self {
        let mut s = String::new();
        reader.read_to_string(&mut s);

        A { s }
    }

    fn as_b(&self) -> B {
        B { b: &self.s }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8297a0e0fc00d38d478706cbe3d91fcf)

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution. I have one more question, if constructing `B` is time consumed, is there a way to speed up the multiple calls to `as_b` ?

Comment: @SaddlePoint, you could mark it with `#[inline]` so the compiler later may try to optimize it. Otherwise I dont think it would impact too much performance anyway.